# DOMDocument getting link inside a h2

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am using `php`, and `DOMDocument`

What I need to do is get all `href` of `<a>` that is inside a `<h2>` tag

on a page where there is a list like

```
<h2><a href="blablabla">The title</a></h2>
```

There is only one `<a>` in each `<h2>`

What I managed to achieve was:

1. load a document through: loadfromhtml (required for this project)
2. get the `<h2>` in the document
3. get those `<h2>->nodeValue (caption of url)`

so my problem here is that when I tried to do the same `getElementsByTagName('a')` on the `<h2>` nodes (#2) the php hangs (no more output produced, page loading stops)

Where do I do wrong? Help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Turn on error reporting. If PHP stops producing output, you likely have a fatal error. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: VolkerK's answer is the correct one, but thanks Michael Berkowski for those show error, I've used it to debug my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me, e.g.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml(data());

foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName('h2') as $h2 ) {
    foreach( $h2->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a ) {
        echo $a->getAttribute('href'), ': ', $a->nodeValue, "\n";
    }
}

function data() {
    return <<< eoh
<html>
    <head><title>...</title></head>
    <body>
        <h2><a href="link1">header 1</a></h2>
        <p>yadda yadda</p>
        <h2><a href="link2">header 2</a></h2>
        <p>yadda yadda</p>
        <h2><a href="link3">header 3</a></h2>
        <p>yadda yadda</p>
    </body>
</html>
eoh;
}
```

But I find it easier to use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) for this
e.g.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadhtml(data());
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach( $xpath->query('/html/body//h2/a') as $a) {
    echo $a->getAttribute('href'), ": ", $a->nodeValue, "\n";
}

function data() {
    return <<< eoh
<html>
    <head><title>...</title></head>
    <body>
        <h2><a href="link1">header 1</a></h2>
        <p>yadda yadda</p>
        <h2><a href="link2">header 2</a></h2>
        <p>yadda yadda</p>
        <h2><a href="link3">header 3</a></h2>
        <p>yadda yadda</p>
    </body>
</html>
eoh;
}
```

prints

```
link1: header 1
link2: header 2
link3: header 3
```